# How can you convert a Dictionary into a DataTable? (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, datatable

How can you take any random Dictionary<object, object> and turn it into a DataTable?

I had to accomplish this task for populating a ComboBox in one of my applications with data that was stored in the properties of a few custom objects.

Comment: Do you expect to create a single column `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I accomplished this. This method makes use of my own custom "IsNullOrEmpty" and "LogError" methods. You can take these references out or replace them with your own if you wish.

I use this in my application by using Linq to automatically convert whatever random dictionary of any type that I may have into a generatic Dictionary<object, object> like so:

```
DictionaryOfObjectsToDataTable(districts.ToDictionary(p => (object)p.Key, p => (object)p.Value), "KeyNameHere");
```

And here's the code of the main method that does the work:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Turns a generic dictionary of object into a datatable, by assuming that the key is the Primary Key column, and the Object's properties are the columns
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The input Dictionary</param>
    /// <param name="keyName">The Name to give to the Primary Key of the table, the Key of the Dictionary</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataTable DictionaryOfObjectsToDataTable(Dictionary<object, object> input, string keyName)
    {
        try
        {

            //Inspect the first object to see if it's a valid object, if not, error out
            if (IsNullOrEmpty(input.First().Value)) throw new Exception("First value in the dictionary was not a valid object. Unable to use dictionary.");

            DataTable output = new DataTable();
            //Add the keys as the first column and set it as the primary key
            DataColumn key = new DataColumn(keyName);
            output.Columns.Add(key);
            output.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { key };

            foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> kvp in input)
            {
                DataRow dr = output.NewRow();
                dr[keyName] = kvp.Key;

                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in kvp.Value.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (!output.Columns.Contains(pi.Name)) output.Columns.Add(pi.Name);
                    dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(kvp.Value, null);
                }
                output.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            return output;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I just wanted to share this for anyone in the future that might need to solve a similar problem.

Comment: I would recommend caching the `GetProperties` outside the `kvp` loop, and putting in the type when adding each column.

Comment: I might also pre-load the columns to avoid unnecessary `Contains` searches for every row.